# How can i use connection pool in perl-redis

Tags: perl, redis, connection-pooling, mojolicious

I'm currently using the Perl language and the Mojo framework, and Redis-1.999(https://metacpan.org/pod/Redis) library.

If I want to use a connection pool, do I have to implement the objects associated with the connection pool directly? I want to use the option to create a connection and define the maximum number of clients, such as the Jedis connection pool.